# It is my life's ambition to get this jQuery to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some jQuery for my first-ever mobile version of a particular page. If I detect a small browser size, I'm showing only a list of articles. Once a user clicks on an article, I want the list to minimize and the article to be shown in the main content. I'm trying to do this by hiding the list when an article is clicked on, but I can barely get beyond the basic step of making the page to anything at all. Here's my attempt to merely put a border around the article list on mouseover:

```
<script>
    if( $(window).width() < 481 && $(window).width() > 0 ) {
        $("div.st_tabs_container").mouseover(function () {
            alert("asdfasd");
            $("div.st_tabs_container").css("border", "3px double red");
           alert("swear words");
        });
    } else {
    }
</script>
```

The only way I can get this to do anything, at all, is by writing ("*").mouseover(function){ . If I'm selecting everything, the mouseover will work and the st_tabs_container will get a red border and the alerts will go off. If I try to select anything else (.i.e  $("div.st_tabs_container") ) it does not work. Can anyone explain this? I'm sure it's something simple, but I am not getting it. To make matters worse, the actual element I need to do things on click is div.st_vertical ul.st_tabs a.st_tab_active . I have had no luck writing code that selects that. Any and all wisdom would be much appreciated!

Comment: This might be easier to troubleshoot if you were able to provide a full (non-)working example.

Comment: Consider posting a jsfiddle link with a failing example. It might also be better to have the title reflect something real about the problem.

Comment: Is this the whole script? If so, you are missing the `$(document).ready()` wrapper. Additionally, the `mouseover` handler will only be bound if the window is between 0 and 481 __when the page loads__.

Comment: Remove the conditional statement and test it then. If it works, then you know its the statement and not the code. Also, if you are making a mobile site, mouseover is NOT the way to go as there is no mouse. AS stated above, if not using domready, this script better be in your footer or it won't work.

Comment: I am completely new at this - is there a better way to determine browser width? I'm not sure how to add things to fiddlesticks, but I uploaded a (completely nonworking) sample here: http://katiebarry.com/writing2.html 

It occurred to me that it could be messing up because another jQuery function controls the articles.

Comment: I was just using mouseover because I'd copied some code from the jQuery site exactly - it's going to be .click

Comment: Fiddlesticks? Click this link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMBWZ/
if it doesn't work, make the screen smaller

html:

```
<div class="st_tabs_container"></div>
```

css:

```
div{
 height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 481 && $(window).width() > 0) {
        $("div.st_tabs_container").mouseover(function () {
            alert("asdfasd");
            $("div.st_tabs_container").css("border", "3px double red");
            alert("swear words");
        });
    }else{}
});
```

Comment: @USK Don't forget to vote up all answers that helped you and accept the answer you think would be most helpful to others!

Comment: Here's an up vote. You should get paid _somehow_ for your labor!